# Establish a https connection, decrypt message

Tags: encryption, https

Trying to establish a https connection. When I send an HTTPS request from the browser to my server, I receive an encrypted message of 517 bytes. I guess it would be a good start if I could decrypt this message, but how?

At the same time, I read that the initial https message is "Client Hello" which is significantly less than 517 bytes. So I feel a little lost here.

Does anyone have time to put me in the right direction?

Comment: *I guess it would be a good start if I could decrypt this message*. What would you decrypt it with?

Comment: If I knew, I wouldn't have asked

Answer (score 0):

See https://tlseminar.github.io/first-few-milliseconds/ for a good write-up on the process that takes place for an https request and response.  As you can see from the article, the information sent from the browser to the server in the 'Client Hello' message is not encrypted, so you should be able to see the plaintext of this message by doing packet capture using [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/).  The same applies to the 'Server Hello' message (which is the server's response to 'Client Hello').

To decrypt the packets containing the HTTPS response from the server, you can use a tool like [sslsniff](https://github.com/moxie0/sslsniff) to capture the encrypted packets.  You'll need to provide sslsniff with a certificate and the corresponding private key.  Your browser will 'see' this certificate for the site, instead of the site's actual certificate, so your browser will need to trust this certificate.

Comment: I'm using winsock TCP in my c++ program. Then I send https request from browser to my program. I thought that the request sent from the browser would start with trying to establish the handshake but the message I receive is "strange characters" of 517 bytes. I have nothing to work with